# OWLAPI: Get the IRI in a AnnotationAssertion

Tags: java, annotations, owl

I have an .owl file like this:

```
...

<ClassAssertion>
    <Class IRI="http://timbus.teco.edu/ontologies/DIO.owl#BusinessProcess"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#bf1badca"/>
</ClassAssertion>

...

<AnnotationAssertion>
    <AnnotationProperty abbreviatedIRI="rdfs:label"/>
    <IRI>#bf1badca</IRI>
    <Literal datatypeIRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Remove_old_books</Literal>
</AnnotationAssertion>
```

What I would like to get, is the class name (BusinessProcess) for the named individual IRI that is declared in the annotation assertion (#bf1badca)

I have the following code that can access the value of the literal in the annotation:

```
        OWLOntologyWalker walker = new OWLOntologyWalker(Collections.singleton(ontology));

        OWLOntologyWalkerVisitor visitor = new OWLOntologyWalkerVisitor(walker) {

            @Override
              public void visit(OWLAnnotationAssertionAxiom axiom) {
                OWLLiteral val = (OWLLiteral)axiom.getValue();
                System.out.println(val.getLiteral());
                // Prints 'Remove_old_books'
              }

        };
```

How can access the IRI field of the annotation assertion, i.e, the value #bf1badca?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IRI field is the subject of the annotation axiom and can be retrieved with the `getSubject()` method.

You can get the matching `OWLIndividual` using an `OWLDataFactory` and calling `getOWLNamedIndividual()`.

Comment: Thank you so much!